# What iphone sdk API can I use to query the iOS word dictionary?

Tags: ios, iphone, database

I'm working on an iphone word game. Is there any way for me to query the word database available in the iOS? The database in very comprehensive and is available when the user selects words. (A popup comes up with the define button)

Answer (score 1):

You can also opt for [LexiContext](http://www.lexicontext.com/). Has a nice bundle for offline access of a whole dictionary, with a singleton shared class and easily available functions to get the words list or description.

But it is not free, but it provides a [sample free sdk](http://www.lexicontext.com/trial.html) for testing with similar to all the functions and access to only words with letter 'a'.